# Check if value exists in array TWIG

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I've got an string loaded from my DB, and global variable from my `config.yml`. I want to check if variable is a part of array given below:

```
app.user.role ='["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]'
```

**I can't change that. It have to look like this.**

I was checking it like this:
`{% if VARIABLE in app.user.role %}`

Global `VARIABLE` is an integer (**and I can't change that**)

But when for example `VARIABLE = 1` my statement returns true, because in `app.user.role` we can find four `1` (in `"1","10","11"`), but i want to find it just in `"1"` not in `"10","11"`.

What I want is to convert `app.user.role` to array or find another way to check if variable is an element of my pseudo array.

I was trying to iterate through `for` loop but `app.user.role` but `app.user.role` is not an array (actualy it is, but with one value `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]`).

Comment: Your app.user.role is not an array, it's a string. That's why a simple `if...in` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string looks like JSON. You can create a Twig Extension class and register there a function that simply returns `in_array`:

```
<?php

class MyExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new Twig_SimpleFunction(
                'inarray',
                [$this, 'inArray']
            ),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param int $variable
     * @param string $appUserRole
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function inArray(int $variable, string $appUserRole): bool
    {
        return in_array($variable, json_decode($appUserRole));
    }
}
```

Then in the template:

```
{% if inarray(VARIABLE, app.user.role) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Not the best but it works.

```
{% set check = '"'~VARIABLE~'"' %}
{% if check in app.user.role %}
```

Now it's working...

Comment: why don't create a helper that transform your string roles in an array then use the classical if var in varArray ?

Comment: I've just did it, `app.user.role` is loaded straight from session, now I transform that into array and It's working as expected